# Fast method to dispatch computation according to tests in a function with array as argument

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Here is a simplified use-case in Numpy of what I am dealing with, how to dispatch some computations?

```
def f(x,th1=0.25,th2=0.75):
if x < th1:
    return x+10
elif x > th2:
    return x+30
else:
    return x+20
```

with x a Numpy vector

```
x=np.random.uniform(0,1,10**6)
```

Of course if I try `f(x)` I get as expected

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Now I can ue a simple loop:

```
%%timeit
 tmp=[]
 for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    tmp.append(f(x[i]))
 np.array(tmp)
```

I get `873 ms ± 8.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

I can also use `np.vectorize`

```
fvec=np.vectorize(f)
```

and

```
%%timeit
fvec(x)
```

gives `248 ms ± 2.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.

But I am pretty sure that someone can give a real boost using "mask" or may be another kind of numpy trick. So, it is your turn... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where` to do this -

```
def f(x):
    y = np.where(x<0.25, x+10, x)
    y = np.where(x>0.75, y+30, y)
    y = np.where(np.bitwise_and(0.25<=x, x<=0.75), y+20, y)
    return y
```

On my system, this runs in `18ms`.

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,10**6)
%timeit t = f(x)
```

runs in `18 ms ± 86.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

while

```
fvec=np.vectorize(f2)
%timeit fvec(x)
```

where f2 is the function as you defined runs on `185 ms ± 2.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: There is no need to use `np.where` which is slower than a bare condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach:

```
def fff(x,th1=0.25,th2=0.75):
    plus20 = x >= th1
    plus30 = x <= th2
    x[plus20] += 10
    x[plus30] += 10
    return x + 10
```

Timings (this one):

```
%%timeit
fff(x)

7.59 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Timings (yours):

```
%%timeit
fvec(x)

201 ms ± 7.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def f(x,th1=0.25,th2=0.75):
    return x + 20 - 10*(x<th1) + 10*(x>th2)
```

which will allow you to use `y = f(x)` without side effects on `x` (as sophros's solution would cause).

If your values are more complex than 10,20,30 you can generalize the approach using the multipliers as index to a mapping array rather than the values themselves:

```
mapping = np.array([20,10,30])
def f(x,th1=0.25,th2=0.75):
    return x + mapping[1*(x<th1) + 2*(x>th2)]
```